# Para c++, arreglos bidimensionales

Tags: c++, array-bidimensional

Estoy creando un programa en `c++`, sobre asistencia electronica. Me está dificultando un poco que cuando ya se haya registrado el numero de cuenta, y yo quiera verificar que el numero de cuenta SI existe, entonces que me brinda un asiento asignado (ESTO ES EN EL CASE 2 del SWITCH).

Estoy intentando crearlo con un ciclo `for` pero no me está funcionando. La pregunta es:

¿Cómo hago que al momento de registrar la cantidad de cuentas, luego yo pueda marcar asistencia y me verifique que esa cuenta existe y me pueda decir que me asigna esta computadora con un arreglo bidimensional, y en el `case 3` me muestre cuales asientos estan disponibles y cuales no?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>


using namespace std;


int main()
{

    int opcion;

    string nombre_clase;
    int cuenta[15], cantidad=0;

    int alumno_cuenta;
    int contar=0;
    int computadoras [3][5];




    do
    {


    cout << "\n\n        **********************\n\n **        <MENU PRINCIPAL>        ** \n\n";
    cout << "    Clase: "<<nombre_clase<<"         \n" <<endl;
    cout << " ** 1.- Registrar Alumno           ** \n" <<endl;
    cout << " ** 2.- Marcar Asistencia          ** \n" <<endl;
    cout << " ** 3.- Mostrar Laboratorio        ** \n" <<endl;
    cout << " ** 4.- Salir                      ** " <<endl;
    cout << "\n\n        **********************\n" <<endl;
    cout << " SELECT: ";
    cin >> opcion;
    cout <<"\n\n";

    switch (opcion)
    {

        case 1: system ("cls"); //ELIMINA EL TEXTO
            cout <<"\n **        REGISTRAR ALUMNO        **\n\n";

            cout <<" Ingrese el nombre de la clase: ";
            cin >> nombre_clase;

            cout <<"\n\n -- Capacidad de 15 alumnos \n\n";
            cout <<" \n ** Ingrese cantidad de alumnos a registrar: ";
            cin >> cantidad;

            cout <<"\n\n";

            if (cantidad<=15)
            {
                for (int i=0; i<cantidad; i++)
                {

                    cout <<"\n Ingrese el No. de Cuenta del Alumno #"<<(i+1)<<": ";
                    cin >>cuenta[i];
                }
            }
            else
            { system ("cls");
                cout <<"\n\n        CANTIDAD NO ACEPTADA ";
            }
            break;


        case 2: system ("cls");
            cout <<"\n **        MARCAR ASISTENCIA        **\n\n";

            cout <<" Ingrese el No. de Cuenta: ";
            cin >>alumno_cuenta;

            for (int i=0; i<cantidad; i++)
            {
                if (cuenta[i]==alumno_cuenta)
                {

                    cout <<"\n\n Alumno registrado a la computadora ";
                    contar++;
                    for (int j=0;j<3; j++)
                    {
                        for(int k=0; k<5; k++)
                        {
                            cout <<"["<<(j+1)<<", "<<(k+1)<<"]";
                            computadoras[j][k]++;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                break;
                }


                else if (cuenta[i]==0)
                {
                    cout <<"\n\n Alumno NO regisrado\n\n";
                break;
                }


            }



            break;


        case 3: system ("cls");
            cout <<"\n **        MOSTRAR LABORATORIO        **\n\n";

            cout<<" Hay "<<(15-contar)<<" computadoras disponibles";


        break;

        case 4: system ("cls");
            cout << "\n\n       Ha salido exitosamente! \n\n\n";


        break;


        default: system ("cls");
            cout <<"\n\nNumero incorrecto, intente de nuevo!\n\n";
        break;
    }

    } while (opcion!=4);

    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
```

Comment: "*no me está funcionando*". ¿Qué es lo que no te está funcionando?

Answer (score 1):

En tu código debes tener cuidado con llamar variables sin definir, como el caso de `nombre_clase` en el menú la primera vez. Te recomiendo el uso de funciones para ir separando el código en porciones más pequeñas y más entendibles.

Me pareció un poco interesante el caso para practicar mi oxidado C++. Si bien, se puede hacer trabajando con vectores y demás, me parece que es más fácil utilizando un arreglo de `Structs` donde va a estar la información de cada alumno. De esta forma es mas sencillo agregar más cosas, por ejemplo si observas, incluí el `nombre` del alumno y otro campo con la `computadora` asignada.

Si puedes notar, además, en el menú hay una opción adicional, `mostrar_alumnos`. Es que inicialmente no se entendía la parte de mostrar laboratorio y terminé creando esa función. Sin embargo como ya estaba hecha, decidi dejarla como aporte didáctico. Si no la necesitas, pues solo la quitas incluyendo del menú.

La línea `cout << string(50, '\n');` es una forma algo ortodoxa de limpiar la pantalla, pero que funciona en cualquier SO. Este código lo compilé en Windows y Linux perfectamente.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Grupo {
    int cuenta;
    char nombre[30];
    int computadora;
}alumno[50];

// ********* Prototipos de Funciones **********
int menu_opcion(char nombredeclase[]);
int cuenta_existe(int num_alumnos, int cuenta);
int registrar_alumno(int ptotal, int pdisponibles);
int contar_computadoras(int num_alumnos);
void marcar_asistencia(int ptotal, int pdisponibles);
void mostrar_alumnos(int ptotal, int pdisponibles);
int buscar_indice(int num_comp, int num_alumnos);
void mostrar_laboratorio(int ptotal, int pdisponibles);

// ********* Programa Principal **********
int main() {
    int opcion=0, limite_lab=6;
    int puestos_disp, nuevos_alumnos;
    char nombre_clase[]="Mi Clase de Informatica";

    puestos_disp = limite_lab;
    do {
        opcion = menu_opcion(nombre_clase); // Mostrar el menu
        cout << string(50, '\n'); // Limpiar pantalla
        switch (opcion) {
            case 1: 
                nuevos_alumnos = registrar_alumno(limite_lab, puestos_disp);
                puestos_disp = puestos_disp - nuevos_alumnos;
            break;
            case 2:
                marcar_asistencia(limite_lab, puestos_disp);
            break;
            case 3:
                mostrar_alumnos(limite_lab, puestos_disp);
            break;
            case 4:
                mostrar_laboratorio(limite_lab, puestos_disp);
            break;
            case 5:
                cout << "\n\n   Ha salido exitosamente! \n\n\n";
            break;
            default:
                cout <<"\n\nNumero incorrecto, intente de nuevo!\n\n";
            break;
        }
    } while (opcion != 5);

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

// ********* Funciones **********
int menu_opcion(char nombredeclase[]) {
    int opt;
    cout << "        **********************"<< endl;
    cout << " **        <MENU PRINCIPAL>        ** \n" << endl;
    cout << "    Clase: " << nombredeclase << "         \n" << endl;
    cout << " ** 1.- Registrar Alumno           ** " << endl;
    cout << " ** 2.- Marcar Asistencia          ** " << endl;
    cout << " ** 3.- Mostrar Alumnos        ** " << endl;
    cout << " ** 4.- Mostrar Laboratorio        ** " << endl;
    cout << " ** 5.- Salir                      ** " << endl;
    cout << "        **********************\n" << endl;
    cout << " SELECT: ";
    cin >> opt;
    return opt;
}

int cuenta_existe(int num_alumnos, int cuenta) {
    int existe = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<num_alumnos; i++) {
        if(alumno[i].cuenta == cuenta) {
            existe = 1;
            i = num_alumnos; // [ Break ]
        }
    }
    return existe;
}

int registrar_alumno(int ptotal, int pdisponibles) {
    int temp_cuenta; // Para mantener el codigo en esta variable hasta que se compruebe si no existe
    int cantidad, indice;
    cout <<"\n **        REGISTRAR ALUMNO        **" << endl;
    cout <<"\n -- Capacidad de [" << pdisponibles << "/" << ptotal << "] de alumnos por asignar " << endl;
    cout <<" ** Ingrese cantidad de alumnos a registrar: ";
    cin >> cantidad;
    cin.ignore();
    cout <<"\n";
    if ((cantidad >= 0) && (cantidad <= pdisponibles)) {
        indice = ptotal - pdisponibles;
        for (int i=indice; i<indice+cantidad; i++) {
            cout <<"No. de Cuenta del Alumno #" << i+1 << ": ";
            cin >> temp_cuenta;
            cin.ignore();
            if(cuenta_existe(i, temp_cuenta) == 0) {
                // Si el # de cuenta NO existe
                alumno[i].cuenta = temp_cuenta;
                cout << "Nombre del alumno #" << i+1 << ": ";
                cin.getline(alumno[i].nombre, 30, '\n');
                alumno[i].computadora = 0; // Inicializado en 0
                cout << endl;
            } else {
                cout << "[!] ERROR: El numero de cuenta ya existe\n" << endl;
                --i; // Para que vuelva a pedir el valor
            }
        }
    } else {
        cout <<"\n[!]ERROR - CANTIDAD NO ACEPTADA \n" << endl;
        cantidad = 0;
    }
    return cantidad;
}

int contar_computadoras(int num_alumnos) {
    int mayor=0;
    for(int i=0; i<num_alumnos; i++) {
        if(alumno[i].computadora > mayor) {
            mayor = alumno[i].computadora;
        }
    }
    return mayor+1;
}

void marcar_asistencia(int ptotal, int pdisponibles) {
    cout <<"\n **        MARCAR ASISTENCIA        **\n\n";
    int num_alumnos, entrada_cuenta;
    int encontrado=0; // Para saber si se encontró el código del alumno
    num_alumnos = ptotal - pdisponibles;
    cout << " Ingrese el No. de Cuenta: ";
    cin >> entrada_cuenta;
    // Verificar si el código de usuario existe en el Struct
    for(int i=0; i<num_alumnos; i++) {
        // Iterar en cada item del vector de alumnos para comparar la cuenta 
        // introducida por teclado vs la correspondiente en el struct alumno
        if(alumno[i].cuenta == entrada_cuenta) {
            // La cuenta SI existe en el Struct
            encontrado = 1;
            if(alumno[i].computadora == 0) {
                // Hay que asignarle una computadora, el numero siguiente desocupado
                alumno[i].computadora = contar_computadoras(num_alumnos);
                cout << "Registro correcto (" << alumno[i].nombre << ") "; 
                cout << "Se asigno la computadora: " << alumno[i].computadora << endl << endl;
            } else {
                // Ya tiene una computadora asignada
                cout << "[!] El alumno COD: " << entrada_cuenta << " (" << alumno[i].nombre <<") ";
                cout << "ya tiene computadora asignada: " << alumno[i].computadora << endl << endl;
            }
            i = num_alumnos; // Para terminar el ciclo for. Es como un break
        }
    }
    if(encontrado == 0) {
        // La cuenta NO existe en el struct
        cout << "[!] El alumno NO esta registrado\n" << endl;
    }
}

void mostrar_alumnos(int ptotal, int pdisponibles) {
    int num_alumnos;
    cout <<"\n **        MOSTRAR ALUMNOS        **\n\n";
    num_alumnos = ptotal - pdisponibles;
    for(int i=0; i<num_alumnos; i++) {
        cout << "Alumno " << i+1 << " | COD: " << alumno[i].cuenta;
        cout << " | NOMB: " << alumno[i].nombre;
        cout << " | COMP: ";
        if(alumno[i].computadora == 0) {
            cout << "< SIN ASIGNAR >";
        } else {
            cout << alumno[i].computadora;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "\nQuedan " << pdisponibles << " alumnos por registrar\n" << endl;
}

int buscar_indice(int num_comp, int num_alumnos) {
    int idx=-1;
    for(int i=0; i<num_alumnos; i++) {
        if (alumno[i].computadora == num_comp) {
            idx = i;
            i = num_alumnos; // Break
        }
    }
    return idx;
}

void mostrar_laboratorio(int ptotal, int pdisponibles) {
    int num_alumnos, indice, contar=0;
    cout <<"\n **        MOSTRAR LABORATORIO        **\n\n";
    num_alumnos = ptotal - pdisponibles;
    for(int i=0; i<ptotal; i++) {
        // Buscar el indice del struct que tiene la primera computadora y asi sucesivamente
        indice = buscar_indice(i+1, num_alumnos); 
        if(indice >= 0) {
            cout << "Computadora " << i+1 << " | Asignada a COD: " << alumno[indice].cuenta; 
            cout << " (" << alumno[indice].nombre << ")" << endl;
            contar++;
        } else {
            cout << "Computadora " << i+1 << " | < NO ESTA ASIGNADA >" << endl; 
        }
    }
    cout << "\nHay " << ptotal-contar << " computadoras disponibles\n" << endl;
}
```